# Rep sharing would be nice

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, questions

**Request**

If your answer is accepted.  It would be nice if you could share your rep with people you felt contributed to you figuring out an answer on this question.

*I don't mean you can simply award rep to comments!*

This would obviously have the unwanted side effect that witty/funny/entertaining comments that don't help towards the question would gain rep.  I am not referring to this.  Only that the person who has their answer accepted can choose to share it with selected participants they feel helped.

**Explanation & Example**

So a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219221/java-is-this-an-endless-loop/20219419#20219419) was a little vague.  After reading the question and the comments I had a more specific idea of what was going wrong.  One of the comments had pretty much hit on the answer before the code was shown (although without direct references to what was wrong of course).  I basically summed it all up in a nice way after waiting a minute or so for an answer.

There was a nice exchange by the asker, asking the previous commenter to write an answer so that they could accept it and a further nice exchange by the commenter just giving me the credit.

Wouldn't it be nice if we could award a little of the rep gained on any question answered and accepted to any participator(s) in the discussion? i.e. I could award half my rep points (and future rep points) on this question to those in the comments that contributed.

Comment: Isn't this what voting on answers is for?

Comment: True but sometimes a question -like this one- is vague and the comments clear up the problem before any one person can solve it.  Having not contributed on the comments, I still used them to form my answer and they hasn't answered by themselves.

Comment: Not really @Andrew. Say I know almost nothing about C++ (it's even true!). But, I do know how to rewrite someone's question so it's understandable. Ross is suggesting that if someone helps the OP to get answers to their questions then the OP might want to give that person some rep. Seems a little complicated...

Comment: -4 votes, wow. People really don't like sharing. :P

Comment: hehe... "My rep! MINE!" That said, it's an interesting proposal with good intentions, so I'm up voting. But I don't think I like it.

Comment: @RossDrew not really. What you actually suggest is awarding reputation on comments, idea that users here don't agree with.

Comment: The way I see it, the possibility of gaining rep through comments would only lead to more comment-answers(and less *actual* answers).

Comment: It's not that they don't like it, it's that they disagree that your feature request should be implemented. There are already plenty of existing ways you can show appreciation to a commenter. Usually I try to suss things out in comments because asking clarifying questions doesn't work well as an answer. If that leads to someone providing a great answer, fantastic. I don't need any more reward than that.

Comment: @RossDrew actually, it [was already proposed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/152859) and rejected without official response.

Comment: @RossDrew that situation is actually pretty common, because newer users are terrible at asking solvable questions. They need a lot of prodding and teeth-pulling to provide enough information to actually address the question (or even discover what the question is).

Comment: just to clarify, I'm not asking to be able to give rep to comments.  I'm asking that if your answer is accepted, that you can share the rep with participants who contributed.

Comment: @RossDrew You might consider clarifying that in your question here. I don't think that would increase the agreement with the idea, but I like clarity, and stuff :)

Comment: @RossDrew and you can already do that, by up-voting (as in the answer below) or, more directly, by [offering a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: This might just end up starting a new "Share plz?" phenomenom that we'll have to get rid of later.

Comment: What about discussions moved to chat? What about comments cleared as obsolete after successful improvements of a question or answer? too complicated to do properly, I'm afraid, and doing it wrong would be more unjust than not doing it at all. And why only for accepted answers?

Comment: @Mołot reputation can be taken back when comment is deleted same way like it's taken back when post is deleted, that's not the issue here IMO.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd but if comment is deleted as obsolete, it means it was useful, right? And it's content got implemented into main post. So that's exactly the situation where comment's author *should* get reputation, and should keep getting his share even if comment is no longer there. The very issue is that rep probably *would* be taken back the same way... Same for ones moved to chat.

Comment: Well you could include obsolete posts posters in the rep share option

Comment: @Mołot still doable, reputation gained for post that had +3 score and existed 60 days when it was deleted will be preserved. Same can be applied to comment having certain threshold of upvotes and deleted as obsolete.

Comment: I also don't think this is the same question as the one flagged.  Can those flags be removed and well, should this one?

Comment: @RossDrew flag can't be removed, I fear. In case it will be closed vote to reopen and others might join.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I know it's doable. I just think it should be addressed in the very feature request question ;) as these points are too important to be omitted. I think *most* of my comments on Drupal Answers got deleted once they fulfilled their purpose, you know.

Comment: Also, surprised nobody mention the [Pundit badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) yet - 10 comments with score of 5 or more will give the user shiny silver badge. So just upvote such comment and by this help him earn that badge.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes here, the man asked a legitimate question.

Comment: @DauhFhauc see [my first comment here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209011/rep-sharing-would-be-nice/209015?noredirect=1#comment667892_209011) refering to Ross's "People really don't like sharing". Legitimate idea can be very controversial thus get both kinds of votes.

Comment: @DauhFhauc raises an interesting question.  Are votes (down votes) supposed to be because you disagree with the question or because the disagree with the quality of the question? I know the answer normally (quality), but in a feature request is it the same?
..or is the quality rubbish as well?

Comment: @RossDrew that's how Meta works. Honestly +9/-11 is quite good, much more than I expected at first. :)

Comment: Well, for feature request both downvotes that means "I disagree" and "I think it is unclear and badly written" really counts towards "don't implement this" - and that's pretty OK, as both statements are good reasons not to implement something. I'm tempted to downvote as I don't see any details about situations I described in your request, for example. Not because I disagree, but because I don't think this request is detailed enough. When you will describe algorithm, I may upvote if I'll agree, or downvote if I will not ;)

Comment: @RossDrew another excellent example of Meta behavior is [this poor badge request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209003/badge-idea-for-voting) - it is well written request with full details. It's totally valid and legit request. And it got barrage of downvotes just because users disagree.

Comment: @RossDrew I think they're more of a "disagree with the question". Take a look at [this question of mine that got a lot of love](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196300/i-gave-someone-200-rep-and-a-mortarboard-badge) for reference. The quality wasn't bad, but the community tore me apart :-)

Comment: Not that I'm offended either way, I love a good discussion even if it's not in my favor.  Just nice to clear it up.

Comment: @Ross now that your actual request is clear I have to also disagree: this is way too complex to be really useful. :(

Comment: Controversial topic, always just floating around 2-4 votes on the negative.

Answer (score 12):

This is why you shouldn't be posting answers as comments, or otherwise leaving very valuable information solely in comments.

If you have found the answer to a question you should be posting it as an answer, not as a comment.  We *want* to encourage people to be posting answers as answers, and we don't want them posting answers as comments.

Comment: Problem in this specific case is the user who posted the comment just guessed, answer would be wrong in such situation as it would begin with something like "I guess" or "Assuming [this and that]...".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd They should be moving the comment to an answer once it is confirmed to be correct.  Also the person that did post it as an answer did so before the OP confirmed the suspicion, so the person posting the answer and the person posting the comment were *both* guessing, one person just decided to take the risk and post it as an answer.

Comment: On StackOverflow the majority of my answers are better suited as comments, well. Mostly because I don't have enough reputation to leave comments. I tend to edit them after into full answers once I know the full details.

Comment: Ideally yes, but if other user posted the same answer in the meantime (not based on the comment but rather his own doing) there's a dilemma.

Comment: Yep, and if someone guessed right in a comment, you can reference them in the answer. Then they still get some kind of honorable mention even if the comment is removed and even if they can't be bothered to post an answer themselves.

Comment: @DauhFhauc Then you're mis-using the site and your answers should be deleted and you should stop knowingly breaking the rules.  If you're going to post an answer you should be posting a full answer, rather than posting a non-answer first.

Comment: Actually no, I was the person posting the answer.  I took the commenters guess, and confirmed it by looking at the code.  As the commenter hadn't posted an answer in the next minute or so, I used his comment and the code to build a concise answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd (1st comment) and Servy: when I guess, I don't expect any rep from it. And anyone who tested my guess and found it to be right should post it as an answer - I'll gladly upvote and give him rep for doing actual work :P

Comment: Well, as for both guessing, I don't know that that's true. I've often been in a situation where I ask clarifying questions in a comment, the OP confirms or clarifies, and suddenly 5 answers appear based on the confirmation. Sometimes this may be coincidence, but sometimes the answers have info that could only have been obtained from the OP's comment.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, but looking at the timestaps of the posted content, in this specific case, the OP's confirmation came after the answer was posted.

Comment: I'm talking about in general. Surely you don't think the OP in this case has also planned to have timeline auditing enforced to help decide whether to give rep or not?

Comment: @Servy I answer the questions to my best ability? Sometimes the question isn't clear and I ask for more information in my answer. Why did you feel the need to spread that abuse to me?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sure, in the general case it's common enough that the answer either did work beyond what was in the comment, or had information based on further comments by the OP, which turn it from a guess into an answer.

Comment: @DauhFhauc Because that's not proper use of the site, and your first comment implies that you even know that.  Unintentionally taking the wrong action is one thing, but *knowingly* mis-using the site is something that I have virtually no tolerance for.  If you want to request further clarification you should be posting a comment, not an answer.  If you don't have enough rep to comment, then wait until you do have enough, don't post comments as answers instead.  Answers should strictly be for answering questions, not requesting clarification.

Comment: @Servy It's a catch-22. I can't get enough reputation unless I answer questions, and I can't answer questions if I don't have enough information. I answer them to my *best ability*, and then provide more context and clarify after they add a comment. I don't understand your stance.

Comment: @DauhFhauc If you don't have enough information to post an answer, and you can't comment, then either wait for someone else to comment requesting clarification (which happens often enough) or move along to a question that you *do* have enough information to answer.  You aren't going to be able to answer every question, that is just fact; even if you have all the rep in the world, some questions will never be in good enough shape to answer.  Just move along until you find one you *can* answer to answer.  Posting incomplete, low quality, non-answers as answers reduces the site's quality.

Comment: @Servy I see your point now, thanks. I do tend to delete my poor answers that never get a response back from the OP. Carry on :-)

Comment: @DauhFhauc Take a look at [Should people answering questions with another question get up-votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112867/148672)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Thanks, that was some helpful comment :)

Answer (score 9):

To make anonymous donation:

1. Go to the other user profile.
2. Go over his questions and answers.
3. Find question or answer that is good and correct.
4. Upvote.
5. Reputation shared.

To make public sharing of reputation:

1. Find good answer of the other user.
2. Start bounty on the question containing that answer.
3. Select how much reputation you want to share.
4. Choose "Reward existing answer" and start the bounty.
5. Wait 24 hours and grant his answer the bounty.
   (don't forget to come back after 24 hours otherwise your rep will be lost or go to bounty hunter)

:)

Comment: Just be sure to do it very judiciously ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber judiciously is my middle name! ;-)

Comment: Sha Wiz Judiciously Dow Ard? Or Shadow Judiciously Wizard? Or, Sha Judi Wiz Dow Ciously Ard?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Sha Jud Wiz Ici Dow Ous Ardly is perfect. :D

Comment: That would fall under the heading of anonymous credit, I want credit for my credit :P

Comment: @RossDrew then find good answer he posted and give it a +50 bounty. Will add this option to my post. :-)

Comment: @RossDrew: In which case, bounty him (albeit at the cost of at least 50 rep... you'd have to be feeling generous!).

Comment: #6 is getting complicated, can we get a flowchart?

Comment: @Matt And that would certainly meet the "*share*" requirement!

Comment: @jonsca you were right, five is max(simple_flowchart) - simplified!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I would like some of the reputation from your answer, then.

Comment: @jonsca you got 10. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think you might want to point out not to up-vote to many of the other users answers (that is going through their profile and up-voting answers) or it will probably be reversed as voting fraud.

Comment: @Jack well, I did write "Find question or answer" - singular, just choosing randomly and upvoting everything isn't a good idea indeed.